# FOL definitional theory in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, first-order-logic

I want to put a first-order theory into Z3, an SMT solver developed by Microsoft. This theory contains two objects *obj1* and *obj2*, a function *move* that takes an object and returns an action, and a one-placed predicate *occurs* that takes an action as argument. The theory contains the formula *occurs(move(obj1))*, and I want to make sure that this is the only way in which the *occurs* predicate is true. I do this by giving a definition of *occurs*:

```
forall (A) (occurs(A) <-> (A = move(obj1)))
```

This means that *occurs(move(obj1))* can be inferred from the theory, but *occurs(move(obj2))* cannot. To prove this, I have translated this into Z3 as follows:

```
(declare-datatypes () (( Obj obj1 obj2 )))
(declare-sort Action 0)

(declare-fun occurs (Action) Bool)
(declare-fun move (Obj) Action)

(assert (forall ((A Action)) (
    = (occurs A) (= A (move obj1))
)))

(check-sat)
(get-value ((occurs (move obj1))))
(get-value ((occurs (move obj2))))
```

The problem is that this gives the following output:

```
sat
(((occurs (move obj1)) true))
(((occurs (move obj2)) true))
```

Which I do not understand, because the definition of *occurs* provides all the necessary and sufficient condition for the predicate to be true, so I would think that *occurs(move(obj2))* cannot be true in any model. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Thanks to de Moura I have been able to find a solution for my problem. What I need to do is to provide *unique names axioms* for the actions, which in my case is the `move` function. I need to state that `move` will never return the same element of sort `Action` when it has two different arguments. This could be done in several ways, but I found this the most concise version:

```
(assert (forall ((o1 Obj) (o2 Obj)) 
    (=> (not (= o1 o2)) (not (= (move o1) (move o2))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming constraints that you did not assert. For example, nothing prevents `move` to be the constant function.
The model produced by Z3 is correct. You can obtain the model by adding the command `(get-model)` after `(check-sat)`. 
The command `(declare-sort Action 0)` is declaring a unintepreted sort. 
In the model produced by Z3, the interpretation of sort `Action` contains only one element, and `occurs` and `move` are constant functions. This is a model because all assertions in your script are satisfied by it.

Comment: You say that the interpretation of sort `Atom` contains only one element, I suppose you mean `Action`? I have tried `(get-model)`, but this did not make things more clear for me, because the model for the occurs functions is: `(define-fun occurs ((x!1 Action)) Bool (= x!1 (move obj1)))`. This, to me, seems to say that occurs will only be true if the argument is `(move obj1)`.

Comment: Yes, I meant Action. Regarding, the interpretation of `occurs`, yes it is only true if the argument is equal to `(move obj1)`, but since the interpretation of Action has only one element, it is also the constant function.

Comment: I think I understand it now! `move` will always return the same action object, no matter what argument it has. To solve my problem I will need to define a different action object for each possible argument, for example I will need a constant such as `(declare-const moveObj1 Action)` that will be returned when `occurs` has `obj1` as an argument. This makes it possible to state in the definition of `occurs` that the argument should be equal to `moveObj1`.